# change the url of facebook comments box according to the page?

Tags: javascript, facebook

On my website I have more than 100 pages, and now I want to add facebook comments box to each page. After inserting the page Url to facebook it gave me this code to add to my page, but I do not want to copy and past to each page then change the Url according to the webpage name. In the second code there is the acctual URL to the webpage can I replace it with

```
location.href
```

So that I do not have to change the URL. Is that even possible? How can I do that?

```
  Include the JavaScript SDK on your page once, ideally right after the opening <body> tag.





<div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script>(function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=324524777119";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

2.Place the code for your plugin wherever you want the plugin to appear on your page.

```
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://damnthisfunny.site40.net/1.html" data-num-posts="25" data-width="470"></div>
```

I tried this but its not working :

```
<body>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=324524777119";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

<div class="fb-comments" data-href="+location.href+" data-num-posts="25" data-width="470"></div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data-href="+location.href+"` Your issue lies in this part of your code.  Ensure you are using a valid fully qualified URL.

Comment: well in this case  the url of the current page should show up.

Comment: Are you running server-side scripting, or are each page a static html file being served?

Comment: I tried this as static html file by it self. But I will be using server side scripting. For server side I still having problems with images for example.

Comment: Then on the server-side do a replacement for the url rather than trying to do with something that looks somewhat like javascript.  `data-href="<% =Request.Url %>" `

Comment: `+location.href+` is not valid unless it is some new serverside language I've not seen.  If it's ASP/ASP.NET the example will work for you. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.url.aspx

Comment: i will not be using sever side for the Facebook comment box code

Comment: Then you will need to hard-code a REAL url in each, unless you get really good with your javascripting and can delay the facebook parsing until you can insert the fb-comments DIV programmatically into the DOM.

Comment: Either way the +location.href+ is the issue and using a fully qualified URL is the answer to your question.  Please see: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I was able to solve this using a little javascript.  Where I wanted the comments to appear I used the code:

```
`<div id="fbcomments"></div>
`<script>
`var elemDiv = document.getElementById("fbcomments");
`var markup = '';
`markup += '<fb:comments href="' + location.href + '"></fb:comments>';
`elemDiv.innerHTML = markup;
`FB.XFBML.parse(elemDiv);
`</script>
```

as opposed to the FB code:

```
`<div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://mysite.com/page" data-num-posts="20" data-width="538" data-colorscheme="dark"></div>
```

All is well as far as the comments posting and the code knowing what page they belong to.  The only problem I'm running into is this:  Whichever code I use from above, the link from the commenter's FB profile links back to the comment page with the same /?fb_comment_id= query string.  If i use the FB code the comments will show, but if I use the javascript code, the comments will NOT show up?! I'm lost...

Comment: I've now found that the code im using, when you follow the link from the facebook profile of the commenter, the url looks as such "http:\\sitename.com/page/?querystring" (used \\ for display purposes ;)

so I know the problem with the comments not showing when following the link is because of the "/" following the "page" in the url.  using the code provided by facebook, this does not happen.  Does anyone know how to resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks man (Enlil)! Here is my rework on the last idea, as I am using it only on client side:

```
<div id="fbc"></div>
<script>
    var elemDiv = document.getElementById("fbc");
    var markup = '';
    markup += '<div class="fb-comments" data-href="'+location.href+'" data-num-posts="5" data-width="682" style="margin-top:2em;"></div>';
    elemDiv.innerHTML = markup;
    FB.XFBML.parse(elemDiv);
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src = "//connect.facebook.net/bg_BG/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=xxxxxxxxxx"></script>
```

Thousands thanks!